# Phongap Build wont support Windows 10?

Tags: cordova, windows

Im using Phonegap Build, can you please let me know whether Phonegap Build wont support and generate the XAP for windows 10?

While publishing the xap generated from phonegap windows marketplace says that xap is only compatible with windows 8 OS and not with windows 10. Please help. thanks

Comment: Windows 10 uses appx not xap

Comment: When I add <platform name="winphone" /> in config file, phonegap build only generate xap and not appx. Is there way to generate appx using phonegap build?

Comment: As far as I can see on the PhoneGap pages it doesn't support Windows 10
however Cordova does: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Platform name windows is not enough. You have to set the following to get appx file.

```
<platform name="winphone">
<preference name="windows-appx-target" value="uap"/>
<preference name="windows-arch" value="arm" /> // arm, x86 or x64
<preference name="windows-identity-name" value="identity-name-found-on-your-developer-account" />
</platform>
```

Make sure the author name is set as per your developer account display name.

```
<author href="http://slickalpha.com" email="support@slickalpha.com">Author name</author>
```